# Java double just won't negate! Why?

Tags: java, types, double

For some reason, I'm having trouble negating a double and then returning it when a certain condition is met (which *is* being met). It stays positive, despite any coaxing otherwise.

```
 public static double angleDiffNoAbs(double from, double to, double maxValue) {  
  double diff = to - from;
  double absdiff = Math.abs(diff);

  if (absdiff > maxValue) {
   double newdiff;

   boolean clockwise = false;

   if (from < to) {
    newdiff = maxValue;
    clockwise = true;
    System.out.println("c");
   } else {
    System.out.println("ac");
    newdiff = maxValue * -1.0d;
   }

   System.out.println("from: " + from + ", to: " + to + ", diff: " + diff + ", absdiff: " + absdiff + ", newdiff(limited): " + newdiff + ", wound: " + (clockwise ? "clockwise" : "anti-clockwise"));

   return newdiff;
  }

  double result = ((180d + diff) % 360d) - 180d;
  if (result < -180d) result = 360d + result;

  return result;
 }
```

The result in my JUnit test is:

```
c
from: -10.0, to: 20.0, diff: 30.0, absdiff: 30.0, newdiff(limited): 10.0, wound: clockwise
ac
from: 20.0, to: -10.0, diff: -30.0, absdiff: 30.0, newdiff(limited): 10.0, wound: anti-clockwise
```

I've been looking at this for ages and can't figure out the problem. The JUnit test is below (if it helps):

```
public class AngleDiffTest {
 @Test
 public void testAngleDiff() {
  double diff = Math.abs(Player.angleDiffNoAbs(353, 12, 360f));
  Assert.assertFalse("diff > 200: " + diff, diff > 200);
 }

 @Test
 public void testAngleDiff2() {
  double diff2 = Math.abs(Player.angleDiffNoAbs(360, 0, 360f));
  Assert.assertFalse("diff2 > 200: " + diff2, diff2 > 200);
 }

 @Test
 public void testAngleDiff3() {
  double diff2 = Math.abs(Player.angleDiffNoAbs(-10d, 20d, 10d));
  Assert.assertEquals("diff2 != 10.0: " + diff2, 10d, diff2);
 }


 @Test
 public void testAngleDiff4() {
  double diff2 = Math.abs(Player.angleDiffNoAbs(20d, -10d, -10d));
  Assert.assertEquals("diff2 != -10.0: " + diff2, -10d, diff2);
 } 
}
```

Comment: your code seems to work here. Perhaps try forcing a full rebuild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from: 20.0, to: -10.0, diff: -30.0, absdiff: 30.0, newdiff(limited): 10.0, wound: anti-clockwise
```

This result appears to be from your fourth test case (`testAngleDiff4`), in which you're passing a negative value of `-10d` for `maxValue`. When you do `newdiff = maxValue * -1.0d`, the two negatives cancel out, leaving you with a positive answer.

Comment: Oops, I'm a fool :) Cheers for that. I also found that I was doing Math.abs on the last test case, and then checking that.

Comment: That's what you get for copy-pasta test cases.

Comment: Not a fool.  But you forgot the cardinal rule of debugging: assume that the bug is in YOUR code.

Comment: @Chris Dennett: Not at all, it happens to everyone. Seemingly impossible bugs are often caused by overlooking something simple, and the brain can play tricks on you, making it harder to spot them.

Comment: @Casablanca: I call this PES: "Programmer's Ego Syndrome".  It's where, for the life of you, you just can't see your own mistake because your brain is absolutely certain you can't have made one and auto-corrects what your eyes see.

Comment: @Software Monkey: Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to describe. :) I wouldn't relate it to ego though, it happens regardless.

Comment: More like tiredness and trying to solve crappy trig problems all weekend, lol. It's still not working in places, but it's probably good enough.

Comment: @Casablanca: <grin>. While in pop culture ego has come to have connotations of vanity and arrogant self-importance, it more properly refers simply to the concept of "self" or "I", with connotations of self-esteem or self-image in certain contexts.  I think "ego" is correct in this context.  Anyway, I am not arrogant (at least, I think not), but I use PES in reference to my own inability to see my own mistakes in coding.